# URL Amigável em hospedagem Windows 2003/2008 com site em PHP

Tags: apache, windows, htaccess, url

Preciso converter esse arquivo `.htaccess` para um formato compatível com uma hospedagem Windows na Locaweb.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?link=$1 [L]
```

Em suporte com a locaweb me orientam a ler este link. http://ajuda.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Isapi_Rewrite#Vers.C3.B5es

Porém não estou conseguindo compreender a diferença, sendo que os links funcionam, o que não abre são os arquivos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi utilizado para essa conversão o `URL Rewrite` que é instalado no **Servidor IIS**, onde eu utilizo para rodar meus sites com URL Amigável para PHP.

> Link para Instalar a Extensão: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Como você não deve ter instalado o IIS, eu converti para você pela configuração passada na pergunta e ficaria assim pelo `Rewrite`.

Crie um arquivo com esse *nome* e *extensão* `web.config` e cole dentro esse Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?link={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

*Tem um porém, essa regra pode funcionar se ela for a única `.htaccess` no seu projeto, se tiver mais tem que gerar um pra cada ...*